# Mark Cursor Vertically on Multiple Lines

Tags: cursor, mark

I can enter rectangle mark mode with `C-x SPC`, and then do `C-p` or `C-n` to set mark to the line above or below.

How do I vertically mark multiple lines in one go **without** having to do `C-p` or `C-n` multiple times?

Also, is it possible to set mark vertically to the beginning or end of document?

Comment: Is your question about the package [multiple cursor](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el), or is it a general question regarding rectangle regions? I'm asking because of the tag...

Comment: Its a general question regarding rectangle regions. I do my best to avoid using packages. Feel free to edit the tags.

Comment: What does "Also, is it possible to set mark vertically to the beginning or end of document?" mean? `end-of-buffer` also works in `rectangle-mark-mode`.

Comment: You can give `C-p` and `C-n` and pretty much every moving command a [numeric prefix arg](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Command-Arguments.html). The command is then executed that many times.

Comment: @Tobias - If I'm on line 20 col. 12, I want the cursor to go from here to line 1 col.12 and all lines in between, without doing ```C-p``` multiple times after ```C-x SPC```